# Search method using textbox

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm Creating Simple Search Page Using Textbox and Button
When I try Searching , The results Show only when I type Numbers in textbox

This is my Sql

## class method

```
public DataTable searchname(string value)
{
    string query = String.Format("Select Name from Users Where Name Like '%{0}%'", value);
    return search(query);
}
```

## in code behind

```
protected void ButSrch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView5.DataSource = classobject.searchname(Textsrch.Text);
    GridView5.DataBind();
}
```

it is not the problem The method Working Correctly

But the problem :

I have The following users in table :

```
Maria 56 - Barak - Rano30
```

But When I try To type in textbox *Maria* --> the result is nothing

When I try to type *Maria 56* --> the result is nothing

But when I type in textbox *56* the result show in gridview

anyone can help me ???

Comment: What is happening inside the  `search()`

Comment: public DataTable RunSelect(string SqlSelect)
    {
        connect(CommandType.Text, SqlSelect);
        Dt = new DataTable();
        Dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        conn.Close();
        return Dt;
    }

 public DataTable search(string Query)
    {
        try
        {
            return db.RunSelect(Query);
        }
        catch
        {
            return new DataTable();
        }
    }

Comment: I'm using these method every selection but this time I don't know what's the problem , when typing letters no results shown

Comment: do you think the problem in textbox ??

Comment: I think the code is correct. The possible problem is the **Textsrch.Text** contains odd space char, this cause only _space_**56**_space_ mached the search condition. Maybe you can debug it or try `GridView5.DataSource = classobject.searchname(TextSrch.Text.Trim());`.

Comment: The Same problem :( but you are right , this is the problem because when I type space or numbers , the result shown in Gridview , but could you tell me other solution for this problem

Comment: Can you check what is the value of 'value' field passed. Try adding profiler to your sql and see what query is executed.

Comment: how can I add Profile to sql ??

Comment: when I write Maria in label text and " select where name like '%'+label1.text+'%' , the same problem :/